# How to find difference between values in two rows in an R dataframe using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an R dataframe such as:

```
df <- data.frame(period=rep(1:4,2), 
                 farm=c(rep('A',4),rep('B',4)), 
                 cumVol=c(1,5,15,31,10,12,16,24),
                 other = 1:8);

  period farm cumVol other
1      1    A      1     1
2      2    A      5     2
3      3    A     15     3
4      4    A     31     4
5      1    B     10     5
6      2    B     12     6
7      3    B     16     7
8      4    B     24     8
```

How do I find the change in cumVol at each farm in each period, ignoring the 'other' column? I would like a dataframe like this (optionally with the cumVol column remaining):

```
  period farm volume other
1      1    A      0     1
2      2    A      4     2
3      3    A     10     3
4      4    A     16     4
5      1    B      0     5
6      2    B      2     6
7      3    B      4     7
8      4    B      8     8
```

In practice there may be many 'farm'-like columns, and many 'other'-like (ie. ignored) columns. I'd like to be able to specify all the column names using variables.

I am using the dplyr package.

Comment: Near certain this is a duplicate question - try: `with(df, ave(cumVol,farm,FUN=function(x) c(0,diff(x))) )`

Comment: Why is it a duplicate if OP is looking for a dplyr rather than a plyr answer?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In dplyr:

```
require(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(farm) %>%
  mutate(volume = cumVol - lag(cumVol, default = cumVol[1]))

Source: local data frame [8 x 5]
Groups: farm

  period farm cumVol other volume
1      1    A      1     1      0
2      2    A      5     2      4
3      3    A     15     3     10
4      4    A     31     4     16
5      1    B     10     5      0
6      2    B     12     6      2
7      3    B     16     7      4
8      4    B     24     8      8
```

Perhaps the desired output should actually be as follows?

```
df %>%
  group_by(farm) %>%
  mutate(volume = cumVol - lag(cumVol, default = 0))

  period farm cumVol other volume
1      1    A      1     1      1
2      2    A      5     2      4
3      3    A     15     3     10
4      4    A     31     4     16
5      1    B     10     5     10
6      2    B     12     6      2
7      3    B     16     7      4
8      4    B     24     8      8
```

Edit: Following up on your comments I think you are looking for arrange(). It that is not the case it might be best to start a new question.

```
df1 <- data.frame(period=rep(1:4,4), farm=rep(c(rep('A',4),rep('B',4)),2), crop=(c(rep('apple',8), rep('pear',8))), cumCropVol=c(1,5,15,31,10,12,16,24,11,15,25,31,20,22,26,34), other = rep(1:8,2) ); 
df1 %>% 
  arrange(desc(period), desc(farm)) %>%
  group_by(period, farm) %>% 
  summarise(cumVol=sum(cumCropVol))
```

Edit: Follow up #2

```
df1 <- data.frame(period=rep(1:4,4), farm=rep(c(rep('A',4),rep('B',4)),2), crop=(c(rep('apple',8), rep('pear',8))), cumCropVol=c(1,5,15,31,10,12,16,24,11,15,25,31,20,22,26,34), other = rep(1:8,2) ); 
df <- df1 %>% 
  arrange(desc(period), desc(farm)) %>% 
  group_by(period, farm) %>% 
  summarise(cumVol=sum(cumCropVol))

ungroup(df) %>% 
  arrange(farm) %>%
  group_by(farm) %>% 
  mutate(volume = cumVol - lag(cumVol, default = 0))

Source: local data frame [8 x 4]
Groups: farm

  period farm cumVol volume
1      1    A     12     12
2      2    A     20      8
3      3    A     40     20
4      4    A     62     22
5      1    B     30     30
6      2    B     34      4
7      3    B     42      8
8      4    B     58     16
```

Comment: I believe this isn't the expected output. volume shoud be: `> DT$volume
[1]  0  4 10 16  0  2  4  8`

Comment: I updated my answer so that it provides exactly what OP asked. However, I prefer to leave the alternative solution in my answer as well as that seems like it might be the preferred output.

Comment: I agree with you, @Vincent. The second output seems more logical.

Comment: Thanks - this is great. One question though: I've realised when I use this approach that I need to be sure the dataframe has `period` increasing - eg. if I define it with period=rep(4:1,2), then the row with period 3 & farm A is 4 (vs -6, which would be better, being cumVol(period3)-cumVol(period2)=4-10=-6).  This would be fine except that I'm finding `group_by() %.% summarise()` sometimes reverses the order of `period`.  Is there a way to allow `period` to be in any order?

Comment: Ah, I found it:  replace the `mutate` with: `mutate(volume = cumVol - lag(cumVol, default = cumVol[1], order_by=period))`. Nice!

Comment: Hmmm... unfortunately if `df` is the result of a `group_by() %.% summarise()` it doesn't seem to work. Eg. `df1 <- data.frame(period=rep(1:4,4), farm=rep(c(rep('A',4),rep('B',4)),2), crop=(c(rep('apple',8), rep('pear',8))),
cumCropVol=c(1,5,15,31,10,12,16,24,11,15,25,31,20,22,26,34), other = rep(1:8,2) ); df <- df1 %.% group_by(period, farm) %.% summarise(cumVol=sum(cumCropVol))`. Then this solution fails - volume is just a copy of cumVol... any ideas? Or would you prefer me to start a new question?

Comment: @RacingTadpole See the edits to my answer. Hope that address your follow-up questions.

Comment: Thanks - that does fix the sorting issue, but how do I difference the resulting dataframe? Eg. With `df1` as above, I set `df <- df1 %.% 
  arrange(desc(period), desc(farm)) %.%
  group_by(period, farm) %.% 
  summarise(cumVol=sum(cumCropVol))`, and then apply your original answer `df %.%
  group_by(farm) %.%
  mutate(volume = cumVol - lag(cumVol, default = cumVol[1]))`. I get an error - `Error: binding not found: 'cumVol'`. Or if I call `lag` with `default = 0`, I get a volume column that is just a copy of the cumVol column.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. I added some code to the answer. If that doesn't cover what you want please make a new question where you explain what you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect - thanks heaps. I didn't know about `ungroup`. Sorry to add so much in the comments!

Comment: The problem is that this takes the difference between the last element in the previous group and the current element in a group.

Answer (score 16):

In dplyr -- so you don't have to replace NAs

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
 group_by(farm)%>%
 mutate(volume = c(0,diff(cumVol)))


   period farm cumVol other volume
1      1    A      1     1      0
2      2    A      5     2      4
3      3    A     15     3     10
4      4    A     31     4     16
5      1    B     10     5      0
6      2    B     12     6      2
7      3    B     16     7      4
8      4    B     24     8      8
```

Comment: Ok, that's easy to fix, just replace `cumVol[1]` with `0`

Answer (score 3):

`tapply` and `transform`?

```
> transform(df, volumen=unlist(tapply(cumVol, farm, function(x) c(0, diff(x)))))
   period farm cumVol other volumen
A1      1    A      1     1       0
A2      2    A      5     2       4
A3      3    A     15     3      10
A4      4    A     31     4      16
B1      1    B     10     5       0
B2      2    B     12     6       2
B3      3    B     16     7       4
B4      4    B     24     8       8
```

`ave` is a better option, see @ thelatemail's comment

```
with(df, ave(cumVol,farm,FUN=function(x) c(0,diff(x))) )
```

Answer (score 3):

Would creating a new column in your original dataset be an option?

Here is an option using the `data.table` operator `:=`.

```
require("data.table")
DT <- data.table(df)
DT[, volume := c(0,diff(cumVol)), by="farm"]
```

**or**

```
diff_2 <- function(x) c(0,diff(x))
DT[, volume := diff_2(cumVol), by="farm"]
```

**Output:**

```
# > DT
#    period farm cumVol other volume
# 1:      1    A      1     1      0
# 2:      2    A      5     2      4
# 3:      3    A     15     3     10
# 4:      4    A     31     4     16
# 5:      1    B     10     5      0
# 6:      2    B     12     6      2
# 7:      3    B     16     7      4
# 8:      4    B     24     8      8
```